# Python Undo Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Let's say I have the following two variables:

```
bob1 = u'bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'

bob2 = 'bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
```

How can I get the value of `bob1` to be the value of `bob2`? That is, how do I unroll the unicode formatting but keep the escapped hex value?

If I do this:

```
bob1.encode('utf8')
'bob\xc3\xb0\xc2\xa4\xc2\xad\xc2\xa2'
```

That's not right...

Help!

Comment: If it's your code that's producing the `bob1` stuff, the best advice is "Don't do that". It's a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code points between U+0000 and U+00FF map to the same byte value in the ISO 8859-1 or Latin 1 encodings.

```
>>> u'bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'.encode('latin-1')
'bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
```

Comment: +1 minor nitpick: `ISO-8859-1` and `latin-1` are the same encoding; the latter is an alias