# When is the output of repr useful?

Tags: python, repr

I have been reading about `repr` in Python. I was wondering what the application of the output of `repr` is. e.g.

```
class A:
 pass

repr(A) ='<class __main__.A at 0x6f570>'

b=A()
repr(b) = '<__main__.A instance at 0x74d78>'
```

When would one be interested in `'<class __main__.A at 0x6f570>'` or`'<__main__.A instance at 0x74d78>'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to deal with or [present a byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271670/python-undo-unicode-question/4271708#4271708) such as

```
bob2='bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
```

If you print this out (in Ubuntu) you get

```
In [62]: print(bob2)
bob
```

which is not very helpful to others trying to understand your byte string. In the comments, John points out that in Windows, `print(bob2)` results in something like `bobð¤­¢`. The problem is that Python detects the default encoding of your terminal/console and tries to decode the byte string according to that encoding. Since Ubuntu and Windows uses different default encodings (possibly `utf-8` and `cp1252` respectively), different results ensue.

In contrast, the repr of a string is unambiguous:

```
In [63]: print(repr(bob2))
'bob\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
```

When people post questions here on SO about Python strings, they are often asked to show the repr of the string so we know for sure what string they are dealing with.

In general, the repr should be an unambiguous string representation of the object. `repr(obj)` calls the object `obj`'s `__repr__` method. Since in your example the class `A` does not have its own `__repr__` method, `repr(b)` resorts to indicating the class and memory address.

You can override the `__repr__` method to give more relevant information.

---

In your example, `'<__main__.A instance at 0x74d78>'` tells us two useful things:

1. that `b` is an instance of class `A`
   in the `__main__`
   namespace,
2. and that the object resides in
   memory at address 0x74d78.

You might for instance, have two instances of class `A`. If they have the same memory address then you'd know they are "pointing" to the same underlying object. (Note this information can also be obtained using `id`).

Comment: (0) Please don't talk about byte strings without mentioning what the presumed/known encoding is (1) In fact, adding weight to the reason for using repr(), not everybody gets that CJK character displayed when they print that string; in IDLE on Windows, one gets `bobð¤­¢` ... it should have 4 characters after 'bob' and I see 4 in IDLE but in this SO comment I see only 3; presumably \xAD is treated as a soft hyphen. (2) Useful for unicode strings, not just byte strings. Example: `u'bob\U00024b62'`

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, `repr(obj)` should spit out a string such that it can be fed into `eval` to recreate the object. In other words,

```
obj2 = eval(repr(obj1))
```

should reproduce the object.

In practice, `repr` is often a "lite" version of `str`. `str` might print a human-readable form of the object, whereas `repr` prints out information like the object's class, usually for debugging purposes. But the usefulness depends a lot on your situation and how the object in question handles `repr`.

Comment: just tried it out and i got the following >>> obj = eval(repr(w))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    <__main__.A instance at 0x74d78>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @shaz: What's w? That ought to work with `w = 'a string'`, for example.

Comment: w is an instance of class A, i.e w = A()

Comment: @shaz: In your object's case, it's not outputting a string that can be fed back into `eval`. (That was the original intent of `repr`, but it's mostly been ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `repr()` is that it is used in the interactive interpreter and in the debugger to format objects in human-readable form.  The example you gave is mainly useful for debugging purposes.